# Why does @Bean returning a mock work but @MockBean doesn't work when it comes to preserving Mockito state across threads in a spring boot test?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I have a JMS Spring Boot project, and I am trying to integration test with my JMS Listener, and I use mockito mocks to mock out beans with external service calls.

During testing, I was having an issue where `Mockito.when` / `thenReturn` returns a `null` within my JMS listener.

I was using `@MockBean` for the service in question, but when I used `@Bean` and return `Mockito.mock`, I was no longer getting a `null` value in my mock.

Does anyone know why there would be a difference between `@MockBean` defined like this

```
@MockBean
private Service myService;
```

and `@Bean` defined like this

```
@Bean
private Service myService(){
   return Mockito.mock(Service.class);
}
```

when it comes to testing JMS Listeners? Please note that the spring test will be in `thread[main]`, and the JMS listener will be listening on `thread[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue with this. It turns out that Spring MockBean automatically resets after the test is completed. In the case of my JMS listener, it turns out that the main thread with the test has already completed and the mock has reset. For anyone else seeing the same behaviour, please validate that your main test thread has not completed yet.

Here is the code that I see in [MockBean.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.java#L150-L155)

```
/**
     * The reset mode to apply to the mock bean. The default is {@link MockReset#AFTER}
     * meaning that mocks are automatically reset after each test method is invoked.
     * @return the reset mode
     */
    MockReset reset() default MockReset.AFTER;
```