# @MockBean uses different instance in JMS listener when running multiple Spring Boot tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jms

I've written a Spring Boot Test, that writes into a JMS queue and is expecting some processing via an JMS listener. In the listener, I'm trying to read an object from S3. The `AmazonS3` class should be replaced by a MockBean. In my test I set up the mock like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    MyJmsPublisher jmsPlublisher;
    @MockBean
    AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final S3Object s3Object = mock(S3Object.class);
        when(s3Object.getObjectContent()).thenReturn(mock(S3ObjectInputStream.class));
        when(amazonS3.getObject(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(s3Object);
        
        jmsPlublisher.publishMessage("mymessage");
        Awaitility.await().untilAsserted(() -> {
            //wait for something here
        });
    }
}


@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyJmsPublisher {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void publishMessage(String message) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("destination", message);
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyJmsListener {

    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @JmsListener(destination = "destination")
    public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
        final S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = amazonS3.getObject("a", "b").getObjectContent();
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

But the issue is that when running **multiple Spring Boot tests** , the `MyJmsListener` class contains a mock that is different from the one created in the Test. It's a mock, but for example the `getObjectContent()` returns null. **But** when I run the test alone, everything works fine.

I've tried to inject the `AmazonS3` bean into the `MyJmsPublisher` and call the mocked method there and it worked. So I suspect, that it's because the JMS listener operates in a different thread.

I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712011/why-does-bean-returning-a-mock-work-but-mockbean-doesnt-work-when-it-comes-to) and also set the `reset` to all available options, but does not make any difference. I also tried this OP's approach that worked for them, where I create a mock via the `@Bean` annotation like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
   @Bean
   @Primary
   public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
      return Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);
   }
}
```

But this just has the same behavior as mentioned above.

So can you actually use the `@MockBean` annotation when using different Threads like using a `@JMSListener`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm struggling with the very same issue here. By any chance do you have an update on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Beans with methods annotated with `@JmsListener` are injecting beans leaked from previous test executions when activated by a secondary thread. A practical workaround is to configure the test executor to use an isolated VM for each class to avoid this issue.

For Maven executions you can configure the `maven-failsafe-plugin` or `maven-surefire-plugin` by setting the `reuseForks` option. e.g:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can also easily change the `Fork mode` to `Class` in JUnit IDE tools for multiple tests execution. Example for IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ JUnit Fork mode]

Using `@DirtiesContext` does not work, and unfortunately, I still couldn't find the root cause for this - My hunch is that it could be something related to using an in-memory instance of the ActiveMQ broker, which lives in the VM instance shared by the executions.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue when using the `@JmsListener` annotation in combination with `@MockBean`/`@SpyBean`. In our case using a separate destination for each test class solved this problem:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${my.mq.topic.name}")
void consume(TextMessage message){
...
}

@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "my.mq.topic.name=UniqueTopicName"})
class MyConsumerIT{
...
}
```

As far as I understand Spring has to create a separate JMS Consumer for each topic/queue. This configuration forces Spring to create a separate JMS Consumer for this class and Inject it correctly into the TestContext.
In comparison without this configuration, Spring reuses the once created Consumer for all test classes.